# drop a column with a default constraint

Tags: sql-server-2005

I created a table:

```
create table userTable
(
    userId int identity(1,1) not null,
    userName nvarchar(20) not null,
    joinDate datetime not null default getdate()
        constraint pk_userTable primary key(userId) on [primary]

)
```

Then I tried to delete the column joinDate:

```
alter table userTable drop column joinDate
```

But I got the error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'DF_userTable_joinD_31EC6D26' is dependent on column 'joinDate'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN joinDate failed because one or more objects 
>   access this column.

why is it so?

Also, I want to specify values only for the userName column when inserting a new row, but when I try to do that:

```
INSERT userTable SELECT 'name1';
```

I get the error message:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
> Column name or number of supplied
>   values does not match table definition.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You want to drop joinDate, but you still want to use it?  That doesn't make sense.  Also, you have a default value of getdata() which will populate the joinDate field if you only insert a userName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drop the column, you first need to drop the constraint. Since you didn't bother to name the constraint, you need to find it (if, for example, you didn't notice it in the error message you received).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE userTable DROP CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(dc.name) + ';'
  FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON dc.parent_object_id = c.[object_id]
  AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
  WHERE parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.userTable')
  AND c.name = 'joinDate';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
-- ALTER TABLE userTable DROP COLUMN joinDate;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to insert into this table without hard-coding a value for the `joinDate` column, you can't just say:

```
INSERT userTable SELECT 'name1';
```

You will get an error that the column list does not match the table definition or something like that. So if you want to insert into a subset of columns, you need to name those columns.

```
INSERT userTable(userName) SELECT 'name1';
```

Being lazy and leaving out the column list works for `IDENTITY` columns but this is the exception not the rule (and I don't think it should be allowed since it is misleading).

Comment: Thank you Aaron Bertrand for ur reply. as for my 2nd part of query and from the comments. I did:                                  insert into userTable
select 'name1'
union all
select 'name2' but I get the error: Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: I updated both my answer and the question to make your second question more clear (I wasn't the only one confused by it). Essentially if you only want to insert into a subset of columns, you need to name those columns in the insert list. Otherwise SQL Server doesn't understand which columns you mean.